# DateTime to Microseconds Since Epoch

Tags: julia

How do I get the number of microseconds elapsed since the unix epoch for a given julia datetime?

I keep getting this as a solution but it obviously loses precision.

```
using Dates

dt = Dates.now()
micros_since_epoch = Dates.datetime2unix(dt) * 1_000_000
```

Comment: "I keep getting this" - where do you keep getting this from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The return value is a 64-bit float, which has about 16 significant digits. This is enough to keep track of milliseconds since 1970 (the Unix epoch). The display of Float64 might look confusing, but the following shows precision is not lost:

```
julia> Dates.unix2datetime(Dates.datetime2unix(now()))-now()
0 milliseconds
```

Comment: How do I convert this to an integer number of microseconds though?

Comment: `1000*convert(Int,Dates.datetime2unix(now())*1000)` - the 1000 is the right multiple, as `now()` returns milliseconds. A larger multiplier risks losing accuracy.